# Table-cell and table-footer-group

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/hqu8N/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"><p>one</p></div>
    <div id="two"><p>two</p></div>
    <div id="footer"><p>footer</p></div>
</div>

#container {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

#one {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#two {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
    display: table-footer-group;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Basically i want the green footer to extend over to the end of the blue ID. And also between the green footer and the yellow ID it's 10 px of space instead of 5px. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have to use table display attributes, or could you use more standard floats?

Comment: I could, but i want the yellow and blue one to change size together depending on the content. And with table's is the only way I have been able to do it.

Comment: that makes sense, although there are ways to fake 100% height columns, like http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns or http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: You should read up on tables. This displays exactly as intended. So either use a real table and include a `colspan` attribute, or give up on trying to fake them.

Answer (score 1):

I used `grid` for your case, and a `grid-gap` for a `5px` distance:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#two {
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">
    <p>one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p>two</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arman1373/4xkgd5Lj/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with both the header-group and footer-group.
I solved this by putting a container around my table which specified the basic width. Inside that I put a div with display: table properties as below

```
#tContainer {
  width: 80%;
  margin; 0% auto;
  }

#tData {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
  }

.tDataRow {
    display: table-row;
  }

.tDataRow span{
    display: table-cell;
  }
```

I didn't use table-header or table-footer but defined them separately:

```
.tDataFooter {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  }
```

And the element structure as follows:

```
<div id="tContainer">
 <div id="tData">
  <div class="tDataRow"><span class="dHeader"> xyz </span></div>
  <div class="tDataRow"><span> data sets repeat </span></div>
 </div>
  <div class="tDataFooter"> Footer data </div>
</div>
```

I am hoping someone else has a neater solution but I couldn't get the header and footer to fit at all, not even the header columns to align with the data

Result:

[Resulting table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwCRZ.png)

Comment: Making the question title itself more descriptive will help provide much needed context to those who may be able to help with the issue.